# how to specify multiple strategy in passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am using passport local for authenticating the application .I understood to perform login

Now i wanted to implement registration for the same

I understood we can provide a name to distinguish both local strategy

but i don't know how to invoke them

Login:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/loginSuccess',
    failureRedirect: '/loginFailure',
      failureFlash: true
  }));

passport.use('login',new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
      process.nextTick(function () {
      });
        UserDetails.findOne({'username':username},
            function(err, user) {

                if (!user) { return done(null, false , { message: 'Incorrect username.' }); }
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                if (user.password != password) { return done(null, false , { message: 'Incorrect password.' }); }
                return done(null, user);
            });
    }
));

app.post('/register',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/loginSuccess',
        failureRedirect: '/loginFailure',
        failureFlash: true
    }));


passport.use('register',new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        process.nextTick(function () {
        });
        UserDetails.findOne({'username':username},
            function(err, user) {
                if (user) { return done(null, false , { message: 'EmailId Already exits' }); }
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                return done(null, user);
            });
    }
));
```

where should i configure login and register to pick up corresponding strategy accordingly i am a new bee please revert if someone not understood my question

Answer (score 0):

Updating as cant put code in comment:

Please go through with this article https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

and let us know if you face any issue.

You can define it in your end points ..see below..    here /login is your end point where you will receive your requests and in function do your coding for checking user, etc and send res.json with response to user.

```
 app.post('/login', 
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
       res.redirect('/');
     });
```

Comment: thanks for the reply in the example pointed , the signup and login strategies are name has local-login and local-signup then how is that particular strategies used according to the user action , sry still i am not getting where should i configure that

Comment: can please tell me how to show the flash message in html view rather than jade views

Comment: there are plenty of modules you can use like https://www.npmjs.com/package/flash-messages..

Comment: You have define your end points..see below..    here '/login' is your end point where you will receive your requests and in function do your coding for checking user, etc and send res.json with response to user.                    app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });

Comment: thanks i added it ,but what ever actions i take is always pointing to the failure link app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('login', {
    successRedirect: '/loginSuccess',
    failureRedirect: '/loginFailure',
      failureFlash: true
  }));

app.post('/register',
    passport.authenticate('register', {
        successRedirect: '/registerSuccess',
        failureRedirect: '/registerFailure',
        failureFlash: true
    }));

Comment: i have define strategies as well

Comment: can we show flash message in html view as well can u please point me to a example where it is used